# ESLint missing props validation in Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

Looking through the [official typechecking docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and for some reason ESLint is throwing an error when validating a deconstructed property.

**Working Functional Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

function MyComponentContainer(props) {
  const { data: { loading, error, user } } = props;
  if (loading) { return ( <Loader/> ); }
  if (error) { return ( <Error /> ); }
  return <MyComponent />;
}

MyComponentContainer.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({}),
};

MyComponentContainer.defaultProps = {
  data: {},
};

export graphql(...)(...)
```

**Error Class Component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

function MyComponentContainer extends Component{
  constructor(){...}
  const { data: { loading, error, user }} = this.props; <<<<<<< 'data' is missing in props validation
  render(){
    if (loading) { return ( <Loader/> ); }
    if (error) { return ( <Error /> ); }
    return <MyComponent />;
  }

}

MyComponentContainer.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({}),
};

MyComponentContainer.defaultProps = {
  data: {},
};

export graphql(...)(...)
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true,
        "modules": true,
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "env":{
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "jsx-a11y",
    "import",
    "jest"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-tabs": 0,
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 0,
    camelcase: ["error", {properties: "never"}],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [ "error", {
        "components": [ "Link" ],
        "specialLink": [ "to" ],
        "aspects": [ "noHref", "invalidHref", "preferButton" ]
      }]
  }
}
```

In a functional component ESLint is behaving as expected. However when applying the same method to a class component, unable to validate data. I thought this may be some type of scoping issue, but everything I've tried 'data' doesn't get validated. Looked through quite a few examples and it appears props are being declared properly but maybe I've overlooked something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found another example in where it needs to be declared.

[ESLint React Plugin Docs](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md)

```
function MyComponentContainer extends Component{
  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.shape({}),
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    data: {},
  };

  constructor(){...}
  const { data: { loading, error, user }} = this.props;
  render(){
    if (loading) { return ( <Loader/> ); }
    if (error) { return ( <Error /> ); }
    return <MyComponent />;
  }
}
```

Note: propTypes need to be declared before `constructor` or that will throw another Lint error.